# Get currently set profile in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a few profiles set up in my AWS configure file. How do I check what the current profile is set to?

I am not looking to get the value set on the profile: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/get.html

I am not looking for a list of profiles:
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/configure/list-profiles.html

Question: how do I check my currently active profile in AWS CLI?

Comment: The current profile is what you set `--profile ` to. Sorry, its not really clear what are you asking. There is also `aws sts get-caller-identity` which is more useful.

Comment: Is there a CLI command that will output the value set using `--profile`?

Comment: If you specify `--profile my-profile` you already know the profile. So there is nothing to check. maybe if would be better if you updated your question with some example of what you want to do.

Comment: There is no concept of a "currently active profile". A profile will be 'used' when the AWS CLI is run, but it is then forgotten. The AWS CLI will use whatever profile is specified or, if none is specified, it will use the `default` profile. The profile can also be specified via the AWS_PROFILE Environment Variable.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Thanks @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A good sanity check I use is to run

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Based on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html):

> Returns details about the IAM user or role whose credentials are used to call the operation.

Can give you a hint around which profile you currently have set

Comment: Clean and correct. Still work in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do the same thing and here is the solution I came up with.

First, I had to understand that when you run an AWS CLI command, to run it with a specific profile, you use `aws s3 blahblah --profile myawsprofile`

But I wanted to run commands without having to specify my profile each time.

To do this, I looked in my ~/.aws/credentials
In here, I can see all my profiles.

I moved the profile I wanted to use into the default position.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is always recommended to use a specific profile which accessing aws